# Can changing from public nameservers to running your own harm Google rankings?

Tags: dns, google-ranking, nameserver

I'm currently on SiteGround, which means I'm on their public nameservers.
I wanted a unique private nameservers so I created a NS records in the DNS zone,
And forwarded my domain to it.

Here's example:
NS RECORDS: NS1 >> `00.00.00.00` | NS2 >> `00.00.00.01`
Then submitted the nameservers: `NS1.example.com` | `NS2.example.com`

So after that everything worked fine but I could noticed that my site doesn't appear on Google anymore. but on Yahoo and Bing it does.

I thought this might be the reason because other websites I manage which use the public nameservers of SiteGround do show on Google..

So, Does Changing From Public Nameservers to NS record can harm Google ranking?
I have just switched back to the public nameservers but it can take weeks till my website show up on Google again, if it really the problem..

Comment: Running your own name servers has some drawbacks.  To put them under your own zone, you have to use glue records.   You really should be running several servers at different data centers in different parts of the globe.   That is expensive.   Using DNS servers that are already set up properly is cheaper and more reliable.

Comment: I recommend against using vanity NS for the reasons Stephen gives plus the fact that if the domain name fails to resolve you are often completely sunk. Another reason is that resolution times often increase. Unless you run more than one network, and I mean network, vanity NS servers are not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter what your name server is.

As long as Google bot can read your info, it shouldn't matter.

The only extra point i can add is if there will be too many backlinks pointing to your site from the same IP then it can be an issue. Meaning if there will be other sites with same name server / IP and pointing backlinks to your website then it can be an issue.

In your situation, i don't see that issue.

Comment: I do have cloned installs of my website which i created for testing - Could this affect my Google ranking?

Comment: When Google finds duplicates it usually chooses one to index and ignores the rest.   Google may be indexing a clone rather than the real site.    See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 0):

Each search engine in general can make your site not listed in search results if it discovers that it has continuous difficulty in accessing your website.

Since you're changing nameservers, you're changing the data connection, and there's that chance that during the change that your site is not accessible to the public for a period of time.

I'd suggest visiting google's search console for your website, and set an account with them if you have not already done so, then you should notice the issues they have with connecting to your site (if any).

Then test everything out to make sure anyone can connect to your website (including your friends) and if they can, then I'd wait about 48 hours for the nameserver changes to take effect.

Also, make sure the new nameserver addresses are correct and that the computer you have that is managing them is always online. Don't turn the computer off or you'll break the gateway and users attempting to access the domain will receive a timeout error at best.

Comment: Thank you all for replying! I changed nameservers to hosting's default about a week ago but still no change. about Google's Search Console, I have an account for a long time, and I have verified my ownership of the domain. the console says there are no problems. the weird thing is that my subdomains do appear on Google as first result, but main domain name doesn't

Comment: Is there actual content on the main domain name or does it redirect to subdomain? if it redirects, then that's why.